# Bug Bootstrap 4 and fullcalendar.js - fullcalendar inside a bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I use the fullcalendar.js with Bootstrap 4 modal.

I have bootstrap4 button when I click on it a modal show up with fullcalendar component.

But when It loads for the first time I get this:

[image]

But when I click on the button the next/prev button it works fine

[image]

So how I can fix that.

HTML code

```
<body>

        <div id="content">

            <button id="btn-calendar" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-calendar"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-calendar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-calendar-title" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-calendar-title">Calendar</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="calendar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- script tags -->
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#btn-calendar {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: how and where are you initialising the calendar? If it's already initialised before you open the modal then probably you need to make it re-render when you open the modal, otherwise it will have calculated the position for various calendar items based on the widths of the elements, which, when hidden, are 0.

Comment: Thank you I create the object only after the modal is open for the first time and It works.

Answer (score 2):

It works if I create the object after the modal is open for the first time.

//app.js

```
$(function() {
    var render = () => {
        console.log('render after modal is open');   
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // setup
        })
        $('.modal').unbind('shown.bs.modal', render)
    }
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', render)
})
```